# Is there a weakly typed / type unsafe lazy+functional programming language?

Tags: functional-programming, weakly-typed

I would like to know whether there exists a lazy+functional language with JavaScript style types. Most lazy+functional languages I've seen are very type safe.

One could argue that a type can be defined in some languages that encloses all JavaScript types. Has anyone done something like this already?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by JavaScript style types. However, perhaps you should take a look at [Lazy Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/lazy/).

Comment: What do you mean by "a type can be defined in some languages that encloses all JavaScript types"?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890347/are-there-any-purely-functional-schemes-or-lisps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a "type unsafe" language can be (purely) functional, because part of being purely functional is that expressions have a semantic value that is independent of the machine representation.  ("Type unsafe" is usually used to mean a language where any type can be cast to any other type by identifying values with the same machine representation --- think Assembly or C).

JavaScript, though, is very type safe --- just dynamically typed.  There's no reason you couldn't have a purely functional language with a single static type, like JavaScript; what you probably want to actually be searching for is "purely functional Lisp".  Here are some results:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lispkit_Lisp
- https://code.google.com/p/owl-lisp/
- [Are there any purely functional Schemes or Lisps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890347/are-there-any-purely-functional-schemes-or-lisps)

Answer (score 1):

Wish I'd seen this earlier. If by "type unsafe", you mean "dynamically typed", then yes, I have been working on a dynamically typed, lazy, functional language with strong metaprogramming support since 2011, called "Leisure".

Here is an incomplete, interactive feature overview that **only works in Chrome** (so don't bother opening this page in Firefox, Opera, Safari, etc.): http://zot.github.io/Leisure/?load=doc/LeisureFeatures.org

The project page is here: https://github.com/zot/Leisure

Leisure compiles to JavaScript and runs both in Chrome and Node.js. I'm also working on a Leisure-based shell right now :).

I haven't really made an announcement about this yet because I'm not satisfied with the stack traces, yet -- lazy languages need special stack trace support.

If you're interested in dynamic, lazy, functional languages, please check it out and let me know what you think.